# FindFirstFile() show address

Tags: c++, file, function, find

I used function FindFirstFile() but i received only memory address - not a file name.

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA File_Data;  

    FindFirstFile(TEXT("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\temp\\*.tmp"), &File_Data);
    cout<<File_Data.cFileName;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you building a UNICODE application?  (Or, to ask another way, what is the type of `WIN32_FIND_DATA::cFileName`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably compiling using the Unicode character set, which means that windows API's will default all character strings to the wide version (wchar_t vs char). Try using the wide output version of `cout` (`wcout`):

```
wcout<<File_Data.cFileName;
```